# Qt 4.8.2. Команды ручной компиляции проекта. Настройка другой IDE для компиляции Qt-проектов

Tags: c++, qt, компиляция, mingw

Интересует такой вопрос: Как правильно собрать Qt-проект вручную? (Без использования среды разработки QtCreator из cmd).

Использую компилятор MinGW, поэтому хотелось бы узнать команды компиляции и ее особенности для QT-проектов именно для этого компилятора.

При qmake *pro пишет ошибку

> QMAKESPEC has not been set, so configuration cannot be deduced. Error
>   processing project file: Calculator.pro.

И еще вопрос:

Можно ли настроить другую IDE (скажем Geany) для компиляции Qt-проектов и что для этого нужно сделать?

Comment: Тот  же путь, что и с Креатором. qmake *.pro потом make ...

Comment: @AlexanderChernin При qmake *pro пишет ошибку QMAKESPEC has not been set, so configuration can not be deduced. Error processing project file: Calculator.pro.

Comment: У меня скрипт для сборки программы из командной строки выглядит следующим образом: создаем папку для билда, встаем в нее, `C:\Qt\Qt5.7_x64\bin\qmake.exe $pro_path -r -spec win32-g++` (pro_path это как ни странно путь к файлу pro, потом `mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release -j 12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, вывел я компилятор QtCreator в консоль IDE, скопировал его команды в cmd и все заработало... Привожу команды компиляции. Объясните, пожалуйста, что они значат.

> C:\Qt\4.8.2\bin\qmake.exe C:\Qt\untitled\untitled.pro -r -spec
>   win32-g++ "CONFIG+=declarative_debug"
>
> C:\Users\User\Documents\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe

Интерисуют команды 
 `-r` , `-spec` и `CONFIG+=declarative_debug` Остальное это пути к файлам, я так понял.

Comment: Считаю что вам можно начать разбираться в cmake и тогда нибудет никаких проблем, две команды и все собрано