# Как добавить QMAKESPEC через cmd на Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, компиляция, windows-7, mingw

В общем дело такое: при компиляции Qt-проекта через cmd на Windows 7 (компилятор MinGW 4.4) выдает ошибку

> QMAKESPEC has not been set, so configuration cannot be deduced

Порылся в интернете. В Linux этот QMAKESPEC можно добавить через терминал командой наподобие (В разном Linux по-разному)

> export QMAKESPEC=freebsd-g++

Есть ли подобная команда на cmd Windows 7? Или может что-то нужно в pro-файл добавить? Пожалуйста, опишите подробно, как скомпилировать проект вручную. Первый вопрос на эту тему [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946755/qt-4-8-2-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-ide-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Скриншот командной строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам уже ответили в комментарии.

Comment: В первом вопросе. И очень похоже на правду ответили - у меня по крайней мере собралось

Comment: Это переменная окружения в которой указывается путь к конфигурации qmake, либо к локальному компилятору в качестве которого вы можете указать ваш мингв. Вот тут подробнее https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qmake-manual-5.html

Comment: @vegorov по той команде из первого вопроса компилятору не удаётся найти файл .pro

Comment: @Konstantin_SH В смысле ? Добавляете в PATH папку с qmake и папку с mingw32-make, и всё. Вы же не просто скопировали пример из комментария, а подменили все пути на свои, правда ? Или Вы прям так и писали `qmake *pro` ? Или `$pro_path`

Comment: @vegorov путь к файлу изменил конечно.

Comment: Больше вопросов богу вопросов? Я вам в комментарии написал команды. Если у вас что-то не получилось, давайте проверять. Скорее всего криво задали путь к .`pro`, относительный, например. Или в кавычки не взяли путь с пробелом.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver У меня команда выглядит следующим образом: 

C:\Qt\4.8.2\bin\qmake.exe $С:\Qt\Calculator|Calculator.pro -r -spec win32-g++

Сейчас добавлю скрин командной строки

Comment: Если это bat файл, то емнип бакс не нужен. У меня скрипт для powershell, там так переменные обозначаются. Не большой знаток bat, но смущает разделитель пути и названия файла, это часом не опечатка? Вместо `|` казалось бы должен быть `\\`

Comment: Доллар убирайте, он же вам пишет, что не может найти файл `$C:\blah-blah`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Теперь пишет что mingw32-make не определена, как внутренняя или внешняя команда

Comment: Укажите полный путь к `mingw32-make` или добавьте ее в PATH

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Указал полный путь. Добавляю Скрин командной сроки

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Можно вопрос? А в чем пробема установить QtCreator? Установите его, посмотрите как  он работает, посмотрите на настройки

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Думаю, проблема не во мне. "Он есть у меня", как говорится и даже работает)) Но преподаватель в ярости сказал "Увижу, не приму работу. Набирайте код вручную", Вот и мучаюсь с ручной компиляцией.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH а задача с использованием Qt sdk?

Comment: Откройте креатор, откройте панель Comile output внизу, запустите сборку (желательно предварительно очистив проект) и посмотрите вывод креатора, сравните со своим. Если не отличается, то я чот даж хз, можно попробовать посмотреть, какие переменные среды он добавляет, может в них дело. В рамках оффтопа - преподаватель неадекват.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Да, калькулятор на qt написан.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую, прежде чем работать с командной строкой поработать в редакторе, чтобы исправить все ошибки, которые вы получите при сборке проекта и сформировать корректный и рабочий pro-файл.

Допустим у вас есть папка с проектом, в котором лежит pro-файл, вызываете cmd.exe и в нем переходите в эту папку (команда cd).

Далее последовательно набираетe команды (если у вас Qt установлен правильно, то пути можно и не указывать, но тем не менее):

```
 `<диск:>/Полный/Путь/До/qmake.exe <имя файла проекта>.pro`
```

И сразу же за этим (вы все еще в папке с pro-файлом):

```
 `<диск:>/Полный/Путь/До/mingw32-make.exe
```

Очистка проекта выполняется так:

```
 `<диск:>/Полный/Путь/До/mingw32-make.exe clean`
```

Если вы предварительно все отладите с помощью редактора, то проблем быть не должно